# firebase_admob 0.11.0+1 while i am trying to import that package this error comes in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\motas.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\804bb16bf16b5e91bc08a39b6997ce12\play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating `android\settings_aar.gradle`...
Exception: The plugin firebase_admob could not be built due to the issue above.
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
√ `android\settings_aar.gradle` created successfully.
Building plugin firebase_admob...

Comment: did u solve it ?

Comment: yes i just used another version of the admob package